# Anonymous functions with call syntax in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

How to write somting like this in CoffeeScript

```
foo(function() {
    return doSomethingCompicated();
}())
```

Comment: That is the same as `foo(doSomethingCompicated())`.. why so complicated (pun intended)?

Comment: this is only example... i have annonymous function with multiple lines of code...

Comment: And the same question applies. Why the anonymous function if you're just calling it immediately? Is it a question of namespace pollution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo do -> doSomethingComplicated()
```

compiles to

```
foo((function() {
  return doSomethingComplicated();
})());
```

You could also write this:

```
foo do -> do doSomethingComplicated
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't ask why this is needed, but here is a direct translation (without **do**):

```
foo (-> doSomethingComplicated())()
```

Note the space after **foo**.